# Two point light sources apart for a certain distance, where should I put the convex lens so that images of both sources are formed at the same place?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics

The question is as follows:
Two point light source are 24 cm apart. Where should a convex lens of focal length 9 cm be put in between them from one source so that the images of both the sources are formed at the same place?

The answer I found is
[image]

How do we know that
$$\frac{1}{f} = \frac{1}{-y} + \frac{1}{-x}$$?
I know how convex lens and the equation work but i do not know why the object and image distances are negative for the first source $S_1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is important that the lens formula be applied with the correct sign convention.

One form of the lens formula is $$\frac1o+\frac1i =\frac1f$$
where

- $o$ is the object distance from the centre of the lens;
- $i$ is the image distance from the centre of the lens;
- $f$ is the focal length of the lens

***and***

- Real images and objects have positive values of $i$ and $o$;
- Virtual images and objects have negative values of $i$ and $o$;
- A converging lens has a positive focal length; a diverging lens has a negative focal length

**All of these conventions** must be applied correctly for the formula to work.

It may be that the solution that troubles you uses a different formula and sign convention.  I have quoted the Gaussian convention and formula; the other common one is the Cartesian convention and formula.

I also believe that the expression $(-24-x)$ is a typo;  it does not appear in the following expressions.

Now, for this particular problem:

You are told that two objects, 24 cm apart, each form an image at the same spot.  If the objects were on the same side of the lens, there images **could not be** at the same spot.

Therefore, the two objects are 24 cm apart, with the lens somewhere in between, and the image on the same side of the lens as its object must be a virtual image.  The basic diagram as given in the solution  reflects this.  Note also that $x$, $y$ and $24-x$ are all positive numbers, and $f=9$

Consider the object $S_1$:

It has a converging lens, a real object with a positive object distance and a virtual image with a negative image distance.  Therefore the lens formula for $S_1$ becomes:$$\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{-y} = \frac19$$

Consider now Object $S_2$:

It has the same converging lens, a real object with a positive object distance, and a real image, with a positive image distance. Therefore the lens formula for $S_2$ becomes:$$\frac{1}{24-x} + \frac{1}{y} = \frac19$$
If we add these two equations, the $y$-term disappears, and the resulting expression in $x$ can be re-arranged to give the same quadratic as found in the quoted solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the high-quality answer!